# Equality of trigonometry function.

Tags: trigonometry

I can't seem to figure this out.
Is sin 2x = 2sin x ?
I know this might be a silly question but I don't know.

Comment: Please try and use titles which reflect the mathematical content of the question.

Comment: What if $x=\pi/2$?

Comment: figured it out thank you for you help :)

Comment: $\sin 2x \neq 2 \sin x$. Look up "double angle identities"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

For example (using David Mitra's example of $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$): $$\sin\left(2 \times \frac{\pi}{2}\right)  =  \sin\left({\pi}\right) = 0$$ while  $$2 \times \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)  =  2 \times \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 2.$$

A correct expression would be $$ \sin\left(2 x\right) = 2 \sin(x) \cos(x).$$

Answer (score 1):

No. $\sin(2x)=2\sin x\cos x$. Not that friendly with addition and multiplication..

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious way to check the validity of a given trigonometric identity is to plug in specific values on both sides of the identity. For example, if you plug in $ \dfrac{\pi}{2} $ on both sides of the given identity, you get $ 0 $ on the LHS and $ 2 $ on the RHS.

Observe also that the absolute maximum value of $ \sin(2x) $ is $ 1 $, whereas the absolute maximum value of $ 2 \sin(x) $ is $ 2 $.

Furthermore, the period of $ \sin(2x) $ is $ \pi $, whereas the period of $ 2 \sin(x) $ is $ 2 \pi $.

All these indicate that the given trigonometric identity is not valid. The correct identity, of course, is $ \sin(2x) = 2 \sin(x) \cos(x) $.